# luaxml always outputs with one letter indentation

Tags: tcolorbox, luacode

I have a code to process an xml file and fill tcolorboxes with its contents. I'm using luaxml but it seems that i always get one letter indentation. Latest luaxml is needed.
The code is here and a picture of the output is given at the end:

sms-sample.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<!--File Created By SMS Backup & Restore v10.08.006 on 12/11/2020 18:37:07-->
<!--

To view this file in a more readable format, visit https://synctech.com.au/view-backup/

-->
<smses count="1" backup_set="10d45e83-2909-4a27-b853-b51113e62e92" backup_date="1605186427168" type="full">
  <sms protocol="0" address="+162738495078" date="1602132754403" type="1" subject="null" body="Voluptatem aut ea sed. Voluptas dolorem nulla aut minima et rerum sequi veniam. Dolore itaque dolores quia. Dolore temporibus nihil quos. Voluptates excepturi sed et harum adipisci ad facere exercitationem." toa="null" sc_toa="null" service_center="+17283940567" read="1" status="-1" locked="0" date_sent="1602132750000" sub_id="1" readable_date="8 oct. 2020 10:22:34" contact_name="content processed by smslib.sty" />
</smses>
```

smsboxes.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{luacode*}
smslib = require "smslib"
\end{luacode*}

\tcbset{tcboption/.is choice,
tcboption/.style={skin=enhanced,finish={%
  \draw[blue, thin, -] (1.60em,1em) -- +(0,20.3em); } },
}

\newcommand{\bubble}[3][tcboption]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[
    #1,colback=blue!10!white,colframe=blue!70!black,
    title={#2},fonttitle=\bfseries]
  #3
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand\printsms[1]{%
 \directlua{%
  smslib.process_xml("#1")
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\bubble[]{\raggedright without smslib.lua (using "senderbox" %
directly in sample.tex)}{\footnotesize address: +91919191919, %
read: 1, service center: +98988783333\\ date: \today
\tcblower
Voluptatem aut ea sed. Voluptas dolorem nulla aut minima et rerum sequi
veniam. Dolore itaque dolores quia. Dolore temporibus nihil quos.
Voluptates excepturi sed et harum adipisci ad facere exercitationem.}

\printsms{sms-sample.xml}

\end{document}
```

smslib.lua

```
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"

-- module
local M = {}

-- template for SMS print
local other_template = [[
\bubble{\raggedright @{contact_name} $\langle$@{address}$\rangle$}{
\raggedright\footnotesize subject:@{subject}, read: @{read}
@{readable_date}
\tcblower
@{body}}
]]

transform.add_action("sms[type='1']", other_template)

M.process_xml = function(filename)
  local f, message = io.open(filename, "r")
  if not f then 
    print("XML file error: ", message)
    return nil, message
  end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  content = content:gsub("\r", "")
  local dom = domobject.parse(content)
  local converted = transform.process_dom(dom)
  tex.print(converted)
end

return M
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line break between `\tcblower` and `@{body}` is responsible for the spurious whitespace:

```
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
local transform = require "luaxml-transform"

-- module
local M = {}

-- template for SMS print
local other_template = [[
\bubble{\raggedright @{contact_name} $\langle$@{address}$\rangle$}{
\raggedright\footnotesize subject:@{subject}, read: @{read}
@{readable_date}
\tcblower @{body}}
]]

transform.add_action("sms[type='1']", other_template)

M.process_xml = function(filename)
  local f, message = io.open(filename, "r")
  if not f then 
    print("XML file error: ", message)
    return nil, message
  end
  local content = f:read("*all")
  f:close()
  content = content:gsub("\r", "")
  local dom = domobject.parse(content)
  local converted = transform.process_dom(dom)
  tex.print(converted)
end

return M
```

[image]

Comment: yes. Same for the part before \tcblower. It was a bit more complicated, i removed the closing curly bracket at the end of $\rangle$ and started the line below with }{\raggedright...